# Watir / Ruby HTML Entities

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm attempting to match meta descriptions in a website, but unable to get past HTML entities.  I've tried escaping the characters and a few other combinations.  If you attempt to match an area of the text without entities there is no issues.   Any help is apprecaited.

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"

include Watir

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

b.goto('http://dev01-new.firestonecompleteautocare.com/cf/oil-change/motor-oil-and-your-car')

if b.metas.any?{ |s| s.html.include? "Ever wonder what color your engine oil should 
be, or what affect temperature may have on it&#63; Learn the answers to these 
frequently asked questions &#38; more, here." }
     puts 'Yes'
else
     puts 'No'
end

b.close
```

Comment: Do not do ````include Watir````. It is not needed and will just pollute the object space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like watir-webdriver allows you to locate metas based on their content attribute.

So you can do:

```
b.meta(:content => 'Ever wonder what color your engine oil should be, or what affect temperature may have on it? Learn the answers to these frequently asked questions & more, here.').exists?
#=> true
```

Note that here you can use the actual characters instead of worrying about the HTML encoding.

Comment: Just to note why your original solution did not work, it was because the html retrieved by watir-webdriver had "&#63;" as "?" (ie no encoding) and "&#38;" as "&amp;" (ie different encoding). Not sure why it is different than viewing the source, but something to keep in mind when matching html.